# Can't updating records from a MySQL database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update records in a MySQL database using a PHP code. The problem is that if there is just one record the updating is working, but for more than one record in the table, the same code doesn't update any of them. I do not know why. Here is a part of the PHP code from the page edit.php ('user' might generate confusion; its about an admin user that is logging with his password and can change data of other users)

```
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['username'];
$pass = $_SESSION['password'];

if (isset($_POST ['updateuser'])){
$UpdateQuery="UPDATE user SET email='$_POST[email]', name='$_POST[name]', surname='$_POST[surname]', grade='$_POST[grd]'";
mysql_query($UpdateQuery, $link);};

if(isset($_POST ['Edit']))
{ $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE idUser = '$user'";
  $p = mysql_query($sql, $link);
  echo '<table border=1 >
  <tr>
  <th>email</th>
  <th>name</th>
  <th>surname</th>
  <th>grade</th>
  </tr>';
  while($record=mysql_fetch_array($p)){
  echo '<form action=edit.php method=post>';
  echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td><input type=text  name=email value=" '.$record['email']. '"></td>';
  echo '<td><input type=text name=name value=" '.$record['name']. '"></td>';
  echo '<td><input type=text name=surname value=" '.$record['surname']. '"></td>';
  echo '<td><input type=text name=grd value=" '.$record['grade']. '"></td>';
  echo '<td><input type=hidden name=hidden value=" ' .$record['idUser']. '"></td>';
   echo '<td><input type=submit name=updateuser value=Update></td>';
          echo '</form>';
         }
         echo '</table>';}
```

Comment: You should try adding ```WHERE id=...``` into sql to specify what row to update. Additionally you should read something about SQL Injection.

Comment: @Keo the records will be updated if you didnt give any conditions.

Comment: @habibulhaq are you sure? One would think that there would be some kind of safety mechanism when doing this from php.

Comment: I am talking about the query. yes it will execute but it will update the whole record of the table.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors, is php_errors, turned on, it would also be helpful for you, if you could access the sql log

Comment: I put the WHERE clause: WHERE idUser='$_POST[hidden]' but has the same effect: no updating if there is more than one record in the table and I have no errors, just not doing update

Comment: There are several problems here: `$user` on line 10 is not defined. Also, a number of these statements have SQL injection vulnerabilities, and you should definitely fix that. The core problem is that your input fields all have the same name - you need to use the array syntax to fix that.

Comment: Aside from the above problems, the structure of the code is going to cause you maintenance problems later on, if it is not already. Mixing logic and HTML can turn into a bit of a mess, as can trapping output in `echo` statements. You'd really find this easier if you did some tutorials first, and then came back to it?

Comment: You never used `mysql_connect` so neither your updates nor your selects should be working...you're not connected to the db. You need to find a db tutorial, and start with a simple example.

Comment: @developerwjk I used mysql-connect in the code but I didn't put it here. From you I learned that I must put the entire code for evaluation.

Comment: @halfer thanks again! I will follow your advices

Comment: No problem. See my profile if you want a good tutorial - it will show you how to do this kind of thing in a much more modular way.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php or http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php or http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php depending on which API you wish to use. However, you cannot mix APIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add conditional clause in you update query.
Try this

```
$UpdateQuery="UPDATE user SET email='$_POST[email]', name='$_POST[name]', surname='$_POST[surname]', grade='$_POST[grd]' WHERE idUser = '$user'";
```

instead of

```
$UpdateQuery="UPDATE user SET email='$_POST[email]', name='$_POST[name]', surname='$_POST[surname]', grade='$_POST[grd]'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Update query does not have a `WHERE` clause, Use somting like this

```
$UpdateQuery="UPDATE user SET email='$_POST[email]', name='$_POST[name]', surname='$_POST[surname]', grade='$_POST[grd]' WHERE idUser = '$user'";
```